# How to deploy Next JS App with Mongoose(MongoDB) connection on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am facing issue while deploying my next js app on vercel with mongodb connection. I have added env variable also on vercel site where we deploy next js app. Is there something going wrong in the below file ?

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://localhost/tasksdb",
  },
};
```

I have add env variable as well into my next js project
.env.local

```
MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://localhost/tasksdb"
```

I establish this mongodb connection from this doc https://mongoosejs.com/. It's provide us to connect with mongodb straightaway .

And this my mongodb connection establish code

```
import { connect, connection } from "mongoose";

const conn = {
  isConnected: false,
};

export async function dbConnect() {
  if (conn.isConected) return;
   
  const db = await connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

  conn.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;

  // console.log(conn.isConnected);
  // console.log(db.connection.db.databaseName)
}

connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Mongodb connected to db");
});

connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Mongodb connected to", err.message);
});
```

Is there something wrong by creating the database this way because in local everything working fine ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think vercel's servers can comunicate with your localhost. You can try hosting your database in the [mongodb cloud](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, but you can not connect to Vercel using localhost. You can use Serverless Atlas version of MongoDB which is free you can host your database there and then connect using the link they will provide.

[image]
See : https://www.mongodb.com/pricing